# Session file not being updated on parent page of AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On index.php, I am running the following AJAX to get updated notifications:

```
function updateNotifications() {

    var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
    var phpSessionId = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>";   
    var number_of_previous_notifications = "<?php echo $_SESSION['number_of_notifications']; ?>";

alert(number_of_previous_notifications);

  $.ajax({
      url : "notification_refresh.php",
      type : "POST",
      data : { "user_id": user_id, "session_id": phpSessionId },
      success : 
       function(data) {

         var response = $.parseJSON(data);

         if (response.messages > 0) {
             $('.inactive-notification-img').hide();
             $('.notification-img').show()
             $('.notification-number').html(response.messages).addClass('blink_me');


         }
         else {
                  $('.notification-img').hide();
              $('.inactive-notification-img').show();
              $('.notification-number').html('').removeClass('blink_me');
         }
     }  

   });
   setTimeout('updateNotifications()', 15000); // Every 15 seconds.


}

    updateNotifications();
```

On the page that AJAX calls, here is the code...

```
if (isset($_POST['session_id'])) { session_id($_POST['session_id']); }
session_start();

include_once('../../inc/database.php');
include_once('../../inc/session.php');


if (
(isset($_POST['user_id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['user_id'])) 
){


$notif_user_id = $_POST['user_id'];



         $search_notif_query = $db1q->query("SELECT id FROM User_Notifications WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$notif_user_id', to_user) AND status = '0'");

         $response = ['messages' => $search_notif_query->num_rows];

         $_SESSION['number_of_notifications'] = $search_notif_query->num_rows;


         echo json_encode( $response );



}
```

As you can tell, in the function on index.php, I am alerting the number_of_previous_notifications to see if it ever changes.  And I let the function run 4-5 times and the number_of_previous_notifications is NEVER updated.

Which is telling me that the session[‘number_of_notifications’] is not being updated on the Ajax request page.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I’ve tried the Ajax request page with and without setting session_id.  That was just a recommendation someone else had made on another post I looked at, but it didn’t change anything

Comment: From what I see in the posted code... There only a `SELECT` performed against the database... Is there something that `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Comment: no.  All I do with this is get the number of items.  Don't actually need the actual data with this call.  The problem is the $_SESSION variable isn't be updated. `$_SESSION['number_of_notifications'] = $search_notif_query->num_rows;`

Comment: So this ajax call is only to fetch the `num_rows` every 15 sec. But is that number supposed to be changing over time and if yes, how? Because that may be the problem.

Comment: it changes when database changes are made.  Thats it.  The number itself is changing and working great.  The ONLY thing that isnt working is updating the Session variable.  I need to set the session variable in the php code on the page that ajax calls, but dynamtically call the session variable on index.php WITHOUT index.php reloading.  But, thats supposed to be possible from everything that I have read by using ajax to reload the $_SESSION variable.  On the page ajax is callnig, I am resetting the php variable...just not getting the updated number on index

Comment: Okay... I'm just trying to understand... Since I'm not able to reproduce. Is `include_once('../../inc/session.php');` your way to check the `$_SESSION['number_of_notifications']` value? And if yes... Is it always `null`?

Comment: no...I just copied and pasted the entire page...that is getting other session variables into the page....I include that and database on everything

Comment: When the index.php page is loaded, the ajax function is called....and then every 15 seconds, the ajax function is called.  Initially, `var number_of_previous_notifications` will be 0.  But when the ajax page runs, the ajax page needs to update a session variable `$_SESSION['number_of_notifications']` with the number of notifications `$search_notif_query->num_rows`.  The next time the ajax function is called, it gets the NEW notification number from the updated $_SESSION['number_of_notifications'] and can function the way I need it to.

Comment: The reason why I'm doing this, is because when the number raises ABOVE what the number use to be, I want to play a sound to let the person know that they have a new notification.  Thats it.

Comment: Is `response.messages` gets updated in the Ajax success callback? If yes... I have no more idea (for now).

Comment: When the ajax page runs, it sends the number of message/notifications to the success : part of the ajax code.    `$response = ['messages' => $search_notif_query->num_rows];` gets turned into `response.messages`.

Comment: but shouldn't I be able to update a session variable like I am and index get the updated session variable being its on the same session file?

Comment: Ho... I think I get it. I think your `$_SESSION['number_of_notifications']` actually get updated. But *«and index get the updated session variable »* looks like the wrong statement here. PHP runs on server-side. Your index.php is already processed and sent to the browser. In no way, PHP maintains a constant communication about it with the client-side. If I'm close to the point, please read [differences between server-side and client-side](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Comment: I think you should consider keeping the old value in a JS variable and on `success`, if that value gets higher, *«play a sound»* from the `success` callback. ;)

Comment: Once the function ends on the first attempt, 15 seconds later, can the variables from the first call still retrieve the old variables created in the first function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... Here is what I suggest you to try in order to play a sound if a stored variable like `old_notification_value` is higher than its previous value:

```
var old_notification_value = 0;  // A variable to store the notification amount over time

function updateNotifications() {

  var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
  var phpSessionId = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>";
  var number_of_previous_notifications = "<?php echo $_SESSION['number_of_notifications']; ?>";

  alert(number_of_previous_notifications);

  $.ajax({
    url : "notification_refresh.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : { "user_id": user_id, "session_id": phpSessionId },
    success :
    function(data) {

      var response = $.parseJSON(data);

      if (response.messages > 0) {
        $('.inactive-notification-img').hide();
        $('.notification-img').show()
        $('.notification-number').html(response.messages).addClass('blink_me');
      }
      else {
        $('.notification-img').hide();
        $('.inactive-notification-img').show();
        $('.notification-number').html('').removeClass('blink_me');
      }

      if(response.messages > old_notification_value){   // Here you handle the sound notification.
        // Update the old_notification_value variable!
        old_notification_value = response.messages;

        // Then play a sound here!
      }

    }

  });
  setTimeout('updateNotifications()', 15000); // Every 15 seconds.
}
```

You tried to handle it from the `$_session` variable... But the thing is that there is no communication between server-side and client-side once the HTML has been produced and sent to the client. Changes on a `$_session` variable **just won't** reflect in the web page already delivered to the client.

In short, you can handle that on client-side only with the json response you have. Forget about `$_SESSION` for that task. ;)

Comment: oh duh!  I was stuck on not being able to make it a global variable because its inside a function...but lost track of initially defining variable outside of the function making it a global variable....ugh....the simple things....

Comment: That was an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I'm quite happy to nail! ;) Happy coding!

Comment: Can I get your help with 1 more thing.... how would I apply a browser onfocus and onblur to this where it only runs when browser tab is focused.  Here is the code, just don't know where to plug what part of my code into..... http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

Comment: Mmm... I would try to add a flag to know if the window currently is in focus when the ajax response arrives.... An additionnal condition could be added where `play_sound` would be a boolean to know if the window is currently in focus. How to have this boolean value is [something like this CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen?editors=0011) --- Have those 2 handlers global ;)